# swagger-codegen on win11 gives: illegal sequence v2\Java

Tags: java, maven, swagger, swagger-codegen

This is my `openApi3` swagger codegen pulgin settings. basic:

```xml
    <properties>
        <swagger-codegen-maven-plugin-version>3.0.0-rc1</swagger-codegen-maven-plugin-version>
    </properties>
<plugin>
         <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${swagger-codegen-maven-plugin-version}</version>
          <executions>
             <execution>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>generate</goal>
                 </goals>
                 <configuration>
                    <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger/ngdms-api.json</inputSpec>
                    <language>java</language>
                    <configOptions>
                        <sourceFolder>src/main/java/com/brightinsight/proxy/ngdms/gen</sourceFolder>
                    </configOptions>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                 <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>3.0.8</version>
             </dependency>
         </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

The input JSON is valid, verified.

when I run the goal, I get the output:

```
...
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 3
v2\Java
   ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error (Pattern.java:2028)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.escape (Pattern.java:2608)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.atom (Pattern.java:2286)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence (Pattern.java:2210)
...
```

There is an [issue `closed` on `swagger-codegen`s page](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/8273), some claiming the rc1 build fixed it, some still experiencing the same issue.

My OS: Windows 11

Comment: It appears there isn’t even a getHandlebars anymore [as of 3.0.0](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/v3.0.0/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/v3/DefaultGenerator.java) (which is where the naive String.replaceFirst was happening).  One commenter does state that “this has been fixed for 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT,” which appears to be the case.

Comment: just added: I'm using version 3.0.0-rc1 of the plugin, but you see it's still there

Comment: Yes it is.  I believe 3.0.0-rc1 is older than 3.0.0 or 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.